# Attendance Monitoring System RFID

Tags: mysql, vb.net

one tap a day, when I tap my card becomes unlimited time in time out, I need only one day in attendance

```vb
query = "select Name from  tbl_time where Name='" & lblName.Text & "' and `Date`=curdate() and Time_out='' "
cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, conn)

dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
If dr.Read Then
    dr.Close()
    Dim ins As New MySqlCommand("Select* from tbl_time where Name,Time_in", conn)

    ins.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MsgBox("You're already login")

ElseIf dr.Read Then
    Dim Tout = dr.GetString(0)
    dr.Close()
    Dim ins As New MySqlCommand("update tbl_time set Time_out=curtime() where Name='" & Tout & "'", conn)
    ins.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Console.Beep(1000, 50)
    timeLog.Text = "TIME OUT " & DateTime.Now.ToString()
    sapi.speak(timeLog.Text)
Else
    dr.Close()
    Dim ins As New MySqlCommand("Insert into tbl_time values('','" & lblName.Text & "','" & lbladdress.Text & "',curdate(),curtime(),'')", conn)
    ins.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Console.Beep(1000, 50)
    timeLog.Text = "TIME IN " & DateTime.Now.ToString()
    sapi.speak(timeLog.Text)
End If
```

one tap a day, when I tap my card becomes unlimited time in time out, I need only one day in attendance

Comment: Here's a quick hint: when you insert an image and it says "insert image description here", you are supposed to insert the description of the image there.

Comment: As for the question, your code doesn't make sense regardless but perhaps you should try providing a FULL and CLEAR explanation of what you're actually trying to achieve and EXACTLY what happens when you try.

Comment: How can this possibly make sense: `If dr.Read Then … ElseIf dr.Read Then …`? If the first call returns `True` then the second call will never be made and if the first call returns `False` then the second call must too.  This is the sort of thing that you end up with when you try to write code without knowing what the code is supposed to do. Put down your mouse and keyboard, pick up a pen and paper and write down a clear, detailed description of what the code needs to do to achieve your goal. Only when you have that should you even consider writing code and the code must follow the description.